# Fail to implement KVO to track BOOL property

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I've successfully implemented the KVO for my keyPath @"isFinished", but I'm not being able to do the same with the other property: isOfflineContentNil;
Its changes aren't registered.

Object:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFinished;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isOfflineContentNil;

@end

@implementation DataManager

-(instancetype)init {
  
  self = [super init];
  
  if (self) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@{@"website" : @"TechCrunch", @"title" : @"New iPhone comming", @"authors" : @"some", @"date" : @"06/08/2014"},@{@"website" : @"TheVerge", @"title" : @"Macbook line refreshed", @"authors" : @"john", @"date" : @"16/09/2014"}] forKey:@"savedNews"];
    self.isOfflineContentNil = YES;
    
    NSMutableArray *userDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedNews"];
    
    if (userDefault) {
      self.savedForLaterNews = userDefault;
      self.isOfflineContentNil = NO;
    }
    
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kLatestNewsURL];
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

    self.isFinished = NO;
  }
  
  return self;
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
  
  NSError *error;
  
  self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                error:&error];
  self.currentNews = [self.json mutableCopy];
  self.isFinished = YES;
  [self sortJSONInformation];

}
```

Listener:

```
self.dataManager = [DataManager new];
  [self.dataManager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
  [self.dataManager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isOfflineContentNil" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isFinished"]) {

    [self animateViewDismiss:self.loadingView];
  } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isOfflineContentNil"]) {

    self.isCurrentNews = NO;
    [self animateViewDismiss:self.loadingView];
  } else {
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't add braces to your if-elses for pasting here, did you?  I worry that the else if for isOfflineContentNil was attached to the if self.isCurrentNews, in which case the if-elses don't do what you hope.

Comment: @stevesliva I edited it, but still not working. Btw the observeValue is not being called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out that I needed to modify the observing option to

```
options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
```

pretty uncommon, but applies to the situation.

Comment: I think this answers is wrong. How about NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew??

Comment: In general its should be both options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew. This way your observer code will be able to handle not only case when observable property is changed but also case when you need to do initial setup since observable property most of all will already have some value when you add observer.

Comment: Wow, this obscure little post, just really saved my cookies. AWESOME. I was using .new but not .initial and could not... for the life of me figure out why stuff did sort properly until AFTER a state change. This was the answer